# xbindkeys and messed up outputs

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, xbindkeys

I am trying to set some key bindings inside a virtual machine.  So I did `xbindkeys -mk` and started testing keys.  The result was somehow not what I expected:

Left wind key ===> `m:0x50 + c:115    Mod2+Mod4 + Super_L`

x ===> `Mod2+x`

ctrl+left-win+x ===> `m:0x54 + c:53    Control+Mod2+Mod4 + x`

First, what should I put in the `xbindkeyrc` and second, why do I get this output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well; `xbindkeys` is supposed to read all the active keys So better first to run `xmodmap` to find out what are your keys more importantly what are your `Mod` keys.
In this case `Mod2` is the Num-Lock key. which you should remove it from the keybindings when you write the `~/.xbinkeysrc`